# Bash - parentheses quoting filename doesn't work

Tags: bash, filenames, quoting

I can't quote the name whatever I do.

[image]

I noticed that   '  is replaced somehow to ` when bash complains.

In the same time I can open file using nautilus.

Any ideas?

Comment: The quotes are just part of the message, not the filename. Try `echo *.dbf | xxd` to see the exact character codes (The first character might be P as well as Cyrillic R etc.)

Comment: oh, God, the first symbol was space - http://kagda.ru/i/d101556d199_26-06-2016-02:36:41_d101.png . how can I accept your comment as answer?

Comment: Off-topic: `ls | grep xyz` = `ls xyz`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: Not exactly, more similar to `ls -d *xyz*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are just part of the message, not the filename. Try `echo *.dbf | xxd` to see the exact character codes (The first character might be P as well as Cyrillic R etc., or there might be an invisible character somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the parenthesis

```
file example\(textinside\).txt
```

Comment: still the same result